# OAuth issue in RingCentral

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, ringcentral

I have three developers. I have try OAuth these three accounts. I can OAuth only to the primary account. For the other two accounts, I got an error message like this:

> "sorry we don't recognise your email address"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some of your OAuth code and what what OAuth grant you are using (auth code, implicit or password grant)? For OAuth 2.0 password grant, you need to use the phone number/extension login. You can verify your credentials for production and sandbox by logging into the following Online Account Portals: production: https://service.ringcentral.com , sandbox: https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com .

Comment: i'm using https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com/ dev box env

Comment: When you receive this error, are you attempting to log into the web UI at https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com or use the API? You can use your phone number/extension to log into both the UI and API. Your email can only be used with the web UI. For email, you need to ensure the user is configured properly. See this page for more info and look for "Use email to log in" - https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/5-10-Editing-Extension-information-of-other-users-via-Web . You will need to configure this for the sandbox at https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com .

Comment: If you are still having issues with this, it would be useful to discuss specific account user information. Please create a support ticket by emailing devsupport@ringcentral.com or join our online chat here: http://glipped.herokuapp.com/

Comment: okay thanks let me check